# Is it possible to develop cross platform packages if am using mac?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I am developing a package that should target cross-platforms,
When targeting the frameworks `net40` or `net45x`, I can't build the project, since the `net40` sdk is not installed on my mac.

Is it possible to develop cross platform libraries on mac, or do I need windows to do that ?

my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>ID</PackageId>
    <VersionSuffix>$(VersionSuffix)</VersionSuffix>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;net451;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' ">
    <Reference Include="System"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Data"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.3' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" Version="4.3.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="ReflectionBridge" Version="0.0.12"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: There is no way to use .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5 cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

When you target `netstandard1.2` or lower, your library runs already on `net45` and `net451` according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library). That is the purpose of the .NET Standard. No need to add `net45` and `net451`.

However, if you indeed require `netstandard1.3` (which is supported by `net46` or higher) and want to target `net40` additionally (which is not supported by any .NET Standard), there is no way to compile it on .NET Core based environment (your Mac). In this case Windows is the only option, since there is no .NET Framework SDK for Mac (which the `net` moniker implies).